# Data Transfer Into New SQL Server Database Schema

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Need to find the best way to transfer data from an existing SQL Server 2008 database into a new database schema.

For some tables the fields in the destination table and source table are lined up perfectly but in other cases a large table in the source is split up into smaller tables in the destination so we need to insert fields from the source table and then get the new key and insert it as a foreign key into other tables with fields from the source table.

Not sure the best way to do this, looks like just a SQL script or an SSIS package but I am not sure an SSIS package can do this.

Comment: The best way to do this is in the tool you are most familiar with. Personally I like T-SQL (batch based) but other people would prefer SSIS (row by row)

Answer (score 1):

SSIS is an option. You'll have to code the data transfers by hand (to get the order correct, to split up the tables that don't map directly), but it'll definitely work. BIML might be able to give you a big bootstrap.